# Setup ec2 to allow ssh connections only with the public key and database connections from custom ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssh, amazon-ec2, postgresql-9.1

First of all, would the above be a good idea? 
Would this be overkill in which the security level will be same using another method?

How would you do this? The alternative would be ssh tunneling from one machine to the database server but I'm not sure if there will be a performance problem from the inbound machine that requires constant connection to query data from the database server.

I can right now ssh into the instance from any machine with the public key.

I can also connect to the Postgresql database on this instance using ssh tunneling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do? Based on the information you provided I have to make a lot of assumptions.

Some general advice when dealing with database servers is to restrict access by both ip and the user connecting to the database. This is only possible if you have a static ip on the client or a known range of ip's that you can use. I'm not sure if either of these cases apply to you. If you're using amazon EC2 VPC you can set your client to have a static private ip and only allow database access from that ip.

Keep in mind that SSH is not the same as access to the database. You will still need to keep port 22 open for you ( hopefully just you ) on both your database server and your client instance so that you can log in and manage those servers.

Like I said before, the more explanation you can give to what you're attempting to do the better someone can help you.

Comment: I guess what I want is, to be able to connect to the database server from a set of restricted ip addresses, without having to use ssh tunneling.

Comment: I have an api server on linode, I want to connect it to the ec2 database server.  At the same time I wish to be able to ssh to the ec2 database server from several different machines that might or might not have a static ip.

Comment: Based on the information you provided you'd need to allow the following ports on your database server's Security Group.

Allow port 5432 from api server
Allow port 22 for 0.0.0.0/0

While it's generally a bad practice to allow port 22 (SSH) for all hosts they would still require your SSH Private Key to log into the host. There are some other options depending on where your other machines are located. Are they all on the same network in an office? Are they inside of EC2? If not you may only be able to open 22 for all or constantly add and remove rules as the addresses change.

Comment: Yeah it seems a bit awkward, I found something that might allow me to do this at https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21009887-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel.  But I'll consider this question answered